# Is there a Priority on Two Sort Fields in Flex for XMLListCollection?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

Is there a priority in the sorting algorithm when you provide two fields for a sort (ISort)?i.e.  if you are sorting on date and time, will the sort only sort time if the dates are equal?

Sample Code Below:

```
private function sortXMLListCollection(listCollection:XMLListCollection, fields:Array):XMLListCollection
{
    var descendingSort:Sort = new Sort();
    descendingSort.fields = new Array();

    for each( var field:String in fields)
    {
        descendingSort.fields.push(new SortField(field, true));
    }

    listCollection.sort = descendingSort;
    listCollection.refresh();

    return listCollection;
}

Function Call: sortXMLListCollection(patchCollection, ["date", "time"]);

Sample XML:
<patch>
  <time>08:44:46</time>
  <date>10/10/12</date>
</patch>
<patch>
  <time>08:51:09</time>
  <date>10/10/12</date>
</patch>
<patch>
  <time>08:46:04</time>
  <date>10/11/12</date>
</patch>
```

Somehow the above function does not work as I expected. I want it to compare the dates first and only sort time when dates are equal.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

your problem isn't your code... it's your xml.

if you add a root node, your code will work as expected:

```
var xml:XML = 
    <root>
      <patch>
        <time>08:44:46</time>
        <date>10/10/12</date>
      </patch>
      <patch>
        <time>08:51:09</time>
        <date>10/10/12</date>
      </patch>
      <patch>
        <time>08:46:04</time>
        <date>10/11/12</date>
      </patch>
    </root>

var patchCollection:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection(xml.patch);

sortXMLListCollection(patchCollection, ["date", "time"]);
```